# opening a specific tab in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 'transactions' page having 3 tabs(**fund transfer, deposit and mini statement**).
I am having one more page containing the menu items. if click on the item, want to open specific tab in transactions page.

I tried in the following way but not working i.e, opening only first tab

```
$scope.openAccountTabs = function(index){
   $state.go("Transactions");
   $ionicTabsDelegate.select(index);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Post the complete code UI routing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it will take lots of changes to make this work.i have tried this and its working.try this

1: change in state definition, pass `$stateParams`

```
.state('app.my_tabs', {
        url: "/{id:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,24}}/{index:[a-zA-Z]{0,12}}",
        cache:false,
        views: {
            'menuContent@app': {
                controller: 'TabCrtl',
                templateUrl: "js/ModelOne/templates/TabView.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

note : id as $stateParams is for passing to API.not related to tabs UI.

2: on button click, pass index which ever tab want to be open(0 = first tab,1 = second tab):

```
ui-sref="app.my_tabs({id:oneOrder._id,index:1})"
```

3: in Tab UI :place on-select in default tab, i had tried using ng-init in ion-tabs , so that method gets call only once. but it didnt work:

```
 <ion-tabs id="tab_view" class="tabs-top tabs-program tabs-color-positive">
    <ion-tab title="tab1" on-select="selectTabWithIndex()">
```

4: here is few adjustment in TabCrtl :

```
 var firstIndex = $stateParams.index;
    $scope.selectTabWithIndex = function() {
        if(firstIndex != null) {
            if (firstIndex == 1) {
                console.log("$stateParams.index :" + firstIndex);
                $ionicTabsDelegate.select(1);
            } else {
                $ionicTabsDelegate.select(0);
            }
            firstIndex=null;
        }
    }
```

note : `firstIndex=null;` is for just to stop checking condition when again tabs are clicked.its my bad logic,make ur own..!

thats its..hola, its working..!all the best.!